# Firebird: Convert date to relevant format?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a SQL query which uses COALESCE to choose the non-null date:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE 
  COALESCE (date1, date2 ) >= '06/11/2013' AND
  COALESCE (date1, date2 ) <= '06/11/2013'
```

The problem is, date1 is a timestamp, and date2 is date. So, if date1 has a value:

```
  06/11/2013 11:00:00
```

IT is not called in the where clause. I.e:

```
 COALESCE (date1, date2 ) >= '06/11/2013' ==> TRUE
 COALESCE (date1, date2 ) <= '06/11/2013' ==> FALSE
```

I assume it's because the time is converted down to

```
  06/11/2013 00:00:00
```

How do I convert '06/11/2013' so the above query will equate to true no matter what time of the day the values in date1 and date2 are? I am only concerned about the DAY, not the hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use Firebird, but from the docs, you might be able to cast a timestamp to a date (by the way, I'm surprised that you can use `coalesce` with different types, but... that's another problem).

So either

```
COALESCE(CAST(date1 as date), date2)
```

or Firebird shortcut

```
COALESCE(date date1, date2)
```

if you got errors, you may try to see what's happening when doing

```
select CAST(date1 as date) from ...
```

Comment: be careful with cast, if you use it a possible index won't be used